# How to Set XML as dataProvider for Charts in Flex?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flex4, dataprovider

I want to display XML exported from Oracle Database as a chart......

The xml has the following structure :

```
<ROWSET>
  <ROW>
        <ORDER_ITEMS_ID>1</ORDER_ITEMS_ID>
        <ORDER_ID>1</ORDER_ID>
        <PRODUCT_ID>1</PRODUCT_ID>
        <UNIT_PRICE>1200</UNIT_PRICE>
        <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
        <ORDER_ITEMS_ID>2</ORDER_ITEMS_ID>
        <ORDER_ID>7</ORDER_ID>
        <PRODUCT_ID>1</PRODUCT_ID>
        <UNIT_PRICE>1100</UNIT_PRICE>
        <QUANTITY>3</QUANTITY>
  </ROW>
```

I've seen many chart examples using ArrayCollection as DataProvider . using the same way , i tried to set xml . But no results.

Can you please suggest me how to set an XML as dataprovider ? ( or XMLList or XMLlistcollection )
( i'm developing a small app in AIR )

Comment: can you share the code you used to make xml the data provider??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea how you mean your chart to look, but here's simple example with XMLList provider for both element based values and attribute based values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
               >
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.binding.utils.BindingUtils;
            import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            private var xml1:XML = <ROWSET>
                                        <ROW>
                                            <ORDER_ITEMS_ID>1</ORDER_ITEMS_ID>
                                            <ORDER_ID>1</ORDER_ID>
                                            <PRODUCT_ID>1</PRODUCT_ID>
                                            <UNIT_PRICE>1200</UNIT_PRICE>
                                            <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
                                        </ROW>
                                        <ROW>
                                            <ORDER_ITEMS_ID>2</ORDER_ITEMS_ID>
                                            <ORDER_ID>7</ORDER_ID>
                                            <PRODUCT_ID>1</PRODUCT_ID>
                                            <UNIT_PRICE>1100</UNIT_PRICE>
                                            <QUANTITY>3</QUANTITY>
                                        </ROW>
                                </ROWSET>;

            private var xml2:XML = <ROWSET>
                                            <ROW ORDER_ITEMS_ID="1"
                                                ORDER_ID="1"
                                                PRODUCT_ID="1"
                                                UNIT_PRICE="1200"
                                                QUANTITY="1"
                                            />
                                            <ROW ORDER_ITEMS_ID="2"
                                                ORDER_ID="7"
                                                PRODUCT_ID="1"
                                                UNIT_PRICE="1100"
                                                QUANTITY="3"
                                            />

                                    </ROWSET>;

            [Bindable]
            private var xmlList1:XMLList;
            [Bindable]
            private var xmlList2:XMLList;


            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                xmlList1 = xml1.ROW;
                xmlList2 = xml2.ROW;
            }   

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <s:VGroup>
        <mx:ColumnChart id="chart1" dataProvider="{xmlList1}" showDataTips="true">
            <mx:series>
                <mx:ColumnSeries
                    yField="ORDER_ITEMS_ID"
                    />
                <mx:ColumnSeries
                    yField="ORDER_ID"
                    />
                <mx:ColumnSeries
                    yField="PRODUCT_ID"
                    />
                <mx:ColumnSeries
                    yField="UNIT_PRICE"
                    />
                <mx:ColumnSeries
                    yField="QUANTITY"
                    />              
            </mx:series>
        </mx:ColumnChart>

        <mx:ColumnChart id="chart2" dataProvider="{xmlList2}" showDataTips="true">
            <mx:series>
                <mx:ColumnSeries
                    yField="@ORDER_ITEMS_ID"
                    />
                <mx:ColumnSeries
                    yField="@ORDER_ID"
                    />
                <mx:ColumnSeries
                    yField="@PRODUCT_ID"
                    />
                <mx:ColumnSeries
                    yField="@UNIT_PRICE"
                    />
                <mx:ColumnSeries
                    yField="@QUANTITY"
                    />  
            </mx:series>
        </mx:ColumnChart>       
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use a xml file as data provider and your file is like

```
<data>
<result month="Jan-04">
<apple>81768</apple>
<orange>60310</orange>
<banana>43357</banana>
</result>
<result month="Feb-04">
<apple>81156</apple>
<orange>58883</orange>
<banana>49280</banana>
</result>
</data>
```

you can do this

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
<mx:Model id="results" source="../assets/data.xml"/>
<mx:Panel title="Line Chart">
 <mx:LineChart id="myChart" dataProvider="{results.result}" showDataTips="true">
    <mx:horizontalAxis>
       <mx:CategoryAxis categoryField="month"/>
    </mx:horizontalAxis>
    <mx:series>
       <mx:LineSeries yField="banana" displayName="Banana"/>
       <mx:LineSeries yField="apple" displayName="Apple"/>
       <mx:LineSeries yField="orange" displayName="Orange"/>
    </mx:series>
 </mx:LineChart>
 <mx:Legend dataProvider="{myChart}"/>
```

You can also use php or any other type of server side coding to render data as xml after retrieving it from any data base.In that case use the source for mx:Model as

> source="http://localhost/yourproj/data.php"

Answer (score 0):

```
[Bindable] private var PIE_XML:XML= <RowSet>
                                                <row>
                                                  <category>red</category>
                                                  <other_data>50</other_data>
                                                </row>
                                                <row>
                                                  <category>blue</category>
                                                  <other_data>20</other_data>
                                                </row>
                                                <row>
                                                  <category>green</category>
                                                  <other_data>30</other_data>
                                                </row>
                                                <row>
                                                  <category>gold</category>
                                                  <other_data>30</other_data>
                                                </row>
                                            </RowSet>;
```

private function init():void
            {

```
            var newItem:Object;
            for(var i:int=0;i<PIE_XML.row.length();i++)
            {
                newItem=new Object();
                newItem.label=PIE_XML.row[i].category;
                newItem.data=PIE_XML.row[i].other_data;

                _pieChart.addItem(newItem);
            }
```

}

from the above code we can convert the XML to array collection then we can use the array to data provider of the chart. solution provided be half of http://digitaladwords.com/